# How to download file from server and zip him

Tags: php, file, download, rar

[Zip and download file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcRnO.png) HI, I want  download file from server and save him as rar. For example: I have file xy which contains file img.jpg and untitled.php. So i want download xy and make it .rar (xy.rar). How to download file from server and make him .rar (zip)?
Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this method: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

All avaliable methods and features which php offers when you want to zip files, are mentioned here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. It merely offers some generic hints which is why it should have been a comment...